# Image background want to remove and set into transparent image

Tags: java, android, xml, image

```
     [It is a sticker app I want to remove image background white color, I need a transparent image][1]
      XML: Sticker view used for sticker adding in image view this sticker file going to save into phone gallery 
            <com.xiaopo.flying.sticker.StickerView
                android:id="@+id/sticker_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:showBorder="false"
                app:showIcons="false">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cropped_image_view"
             />
 </com.xiaopo.flying.sticker.StickerView>
```

**Java**: I set background transparent for both sticker-view and image-view but i got black colour background image in gallery, there is have any option of remove background colour and set image into transparent in programmatic,

```
stickerView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
stickerView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: Give some more details. Only the image is not enough

Comment: I added xml and source code

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file, inside StickerView attribute add:

**android:background="#00FFFFFF"**

Basically #FFFFFF is white and it can be any color, it's the two 0s after # that set your transparency. #00 means 0 Alpha, so total transparency.

This works for buttons as well.